# Web scraping Get responsetext to server

Tags: node.js, web-scraping

Hi guys Ive been struggling for a couple of weeks trying to get this to work. Ive read a ton and im almost close to an solution. I was just hoping someone with more experience then me could help out.

At this point I have:

- An server at digitalocean
- 2 test scripts.

To test my server I have used this code:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
 res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
 res.end('Hello World test sucess\n');
}).listen(8080); 
console.log('Server is running at http://178.62.253.206:8080/');
```

Which is working fine

I just manged to get my scraper script to get the html response text loaded into console using this:

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

request('http://www.xscores.com/soccer', function (error, response, html) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(html);
  }
});
```

I really want to somehow merge these 2 codes. Meaning I would like to load the response text into my server. I've tried a couple of things but I'm not exactly sure how I should phrase the code.

Any help is much appreciated

frederik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should look something like this!

```
var http = require('http');
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
   request('http://www.xscores.com/soccer', function   (error, response, html) {
   if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
       res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type':'text/plain'});
       res.end('html:'+html);
   }
```

});    }).listen(8080); 
    console.log('Server is running at  http://178.62.253.206:8080/');

Comment: This one worked :) Great!!! as a sidequestion Would it be possible to load this into different div elements or tables ?

Comment: You could indeed, you might have to manipulate the HTML a little on the server tho.

Comment: Thanks alot I guess this thread is solved (double solved) Would you mind giving an example to how i Could add this into a div element?, My knowledge is fairly limited unfortunately..

Comment: Well you could do something a little like '<html><div>'+html+'</div></html>'. Though It's probably best to strip the corresponding tags from the source. Ideally you'd use a library to manipulate the HTML, there are lots of ways to do this. I'd suggest creating a fiddle on jsfiddle.net and playing about with your html source. It's fun!

Answer (score 1):

Since you are sending html content, change the `content-type` to `'text/html'` and try this:

```
var http = require('http');
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {

    request('http://www.xscores.com/soccer', function (error, response, html) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log(html);
            res.writeHead(200, {
                'Content-Type': 'text/html'
            });
            res.end(html);
        }
    });
}).listen(8080);


console.log('Server is running at http://178.62.253.206:8080/');
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. I think your code  works , But the site becomes unresponsive. and it loads some info the console after a awhile .  Im not sure exactly whats wrong . Maybe its because this gets loaded into the <head> ?

Comment: Ok I understand. Thanks a lot , I'd give you both rep (unfortunately it does not count)  I  wasn't expecting answers that fast :)  Im not sure if you saw the comment above but I would be intrested in sorting this into an table  and or a div element. then I could start sorting. Im learning all of this as I go and  2 weeks ago i never thought Id come this far ...

Comment: thanks bud , I actually had that tutorial open in one of my tabs:) I think Ill handle the parsing from this point , Its just so much info to dig into ..